# Idempotent Matrix and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $M \in M_{n}(\mathbb R)$ with $M\neq 0 ,  I_{n}$ but $M^{2}=M$. Which of the following are true?

1. Null$(M)$ is the eigenspace of $M$ corresponding to the zero eigenvalue.
2. Let $x\in Col(M)$ with $x\neq0$. Then $x$ is an eigenvector of $M$ corresponding to the eigenvalue 1.
3. Let $x\notin Null(M)$. Then $x$ is an eigenvector of $M$ corresponding to the eigenvalue 1.
4. $R^{n} = Col(M) + Null(M)$

Attempt: First and second options are correct. This is because:

$x \in Col(M)$ $\implies $ $\exists  y\neq0$ such that $x = My$. Pre-Multiplying the Matrix $M$ on both the sides, we get $Mx=M^{2}y \implies Mx=My$. But we already know that $x=My$. Therefore, $Mx=x$ and hence $x$ is an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue 1.

I have an issue with option 3. This option seems correct to me.
The reason is : As  $M^{2}=M \implies $ Rank$(M^{2})$ = Rank$(M) \implies Null(M) \cap Col(M)=${$0$}. So if $x \notin Null(M)$, then $x$ will be non-zero & surely present in $Col(M)$. Then by option (2), $x$ must be an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue 1 too.
But the Answer key for this questions says that option 3 is incorrect.

Please elaborate on the loopholes, if any exist somewhere in my explanation. Thank you for the help.

Comment: A question to the community (and the author of the question). Is *Col* a usual notation for the image of a linear map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint for 3**

Consider

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ and $x=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\1\end{pmatrix}$